# How to set style for RichTextBox?

Tags: gwt, ri

### RichTextBox has such dom level hierarchy?

```
  <iframe>
    <html>
     <body>
     </body>
   </html>
 </iframe>
```

---

I found setting style name to iframe doesn't work,and It must be set to body element.
I tried to do it like this(in constructor):

---

```
  Element body = ((FrameElement) getElement().cast()).getContentDocument().getBody();
  body.setClassName("richTextArea");
```

A NullPointerException got thrown out on this boy element,and even I wrapper them like this:

---

```
  Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand()
  {
     @Override
     public void execute()
     {
         Element body = ((FrameElement) getElement().cast()).getContentDocument().getBody();
         body.setClassName("richTextArea"); 
     }

  });
```

And the actually problem is RichTextBox got rendered weirdly,when it is attached to 
DOM,its inner stuff(html,body) didn't got generated,even I wrapper these lines into
onload() method,NPE got thrown out sometime,but if wrapping them into a timer,then schedule
a  relative long waiting time,no NPEs,but you know,I can't let something depends on this 
unpredicted "relative long waiting time".

Can anyone give a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply CSS rules defined in your main page to the content of your RichTextArea.
You have to include the style in the iframe created by the RichTextArea.

Here is a simple example with inline style:

```
RichTextArea richTextArea = new RichTextArea();
richTextArea.setSize("200px", "200px");
richTextArea.setHTML("<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">h1 {color: red}</style></head><body><h1>Title</h1><p>content...</p></body></html>");
RootPanel.get().add(richTextArea);
```

You can also external css files. the html code set to the richTextEditor must be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Can you tell me why?And I need to register cut/paste listener to body element by JSNI,so I do need to manipulate body element.followed You solution,I still can't get body elemet,and all events doesn't work